# Упорядочить элементы в GridView

Tags: android, android-studio

Я заполняю `GridView` элементами из массива. В зависимости от `position` элемента, после клика по нему я показываю определенный текст в `DialogFragment`. Элементы раскиданы по 5-и столбцам. Проблема в том, что `GridView` заполняется элементами в таком порядке :

```
0   1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8   9
10  11  12  13  14
0   16  17  18  19
4   3   2   1   0
```

(Это значения `position`)

**Как это исправить?** 
Вот тело activity:

```
public class AchievementActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final int a =25;
String[] names1;
Button[] btn;
GridView gv;
ArrayList<Achievement> products= new ArrayList<Achievement>();
AchievementAdapter achiAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_achievement);
    names1= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.achievements_names);
    btn = new Button[a];

    LayoutInflater lnInflater = getLayoutInflater();

    fillData();

    achiAdapter=new AchievementAdapter(this, products, new AchievementAdapter.BtnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBtnClick(int position) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            ...
        }
    });
    gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.GridAchievements);
    gv.setNumColumns(5);
    gv.setAdapter(achiAdapter);
    }

void fillData(){
    for( int i=0; i<a; i++){
        products.add(new Achievement(names1[i], R.drawable.splash_background));

    }
}
```

}

Вот адаптер:

```
public class AchievementAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
LayoutInflater lInflater;
ArrayList<Achievement> objects;
BtnClickListener mClickListener = null;

AchievementAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Achievement> products, BtnClickListener listener){
    ctx= context;
    objects=products;
    lInflater= (LayoutInflater) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mClickListener = listener;
}
@Override
public  int getCount(){
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return objects.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view=convertView;
    if(view==null){
        view=lInflater.inflate(R.layout.case_of_list_of_achievements, parent, false);
        Achievement p= getProduct(position);
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.NameOfTrophy)).setText(p.name);
        ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageBtn)).setImageResource(p.image);
        ImageView vie=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageBtn);
        vie.setTag(position);
        vie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mClickListener != null)
                    mClickListener.onBtnClick((Integer) v.getTag());
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}
Achievement getProduct(int position){
    return ((Achievement) getItem(position));
}
public interface BtnClickListener {
    public abstract void onBtnClick(int position);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправить очень просто.

Вынесите весь код, кроме `inflate`, из условия `if (view == null)`

Исходя из текущего кода, он переписывает значения только если `view` ранее не отображалось, иначе - берет уже существующие